# Override Array Values with another one

Tags: php, arrays

I like to learn how to combine two associative array which has same keys but different values like how we do in jQuery with `var options = $.extend(defaults, options);`

```
$first = array("name"=>"John","last_name"=>"McDonald","City"=>"World"); //default values
$second = array("name"=>"Michael","last_name"=>"Jackson"); //user provided

$result = combine($first,$second);

//output array("name"=>"Michael","last_name"=>"Jackson","City"=>"World");
```

I am looking for something `built-in` instead of writing a entire new function to provide this feature. Of course if you have something neat, just let me know.

Thanks...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$result = array_merge($first, $second);
```

As long as you're dealing with string keys, [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) does exactly what you want. The two arrays are combined, and where the two have the same keys, the values from `$second` overwrite the values from `$first`.

Comment: Yes it's good with one small drawback. Array_merge will reorder numeric keys! So, if you have numeric keys in your array (for example numeric constant values), then you can't use array_merge correctly.

Answer (score 5):

[`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 3):

I think [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or [`array_combine()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) are the functions you are searching for.

Comment: +1 for `array_combine()`. PHP has a lot of great built-in functions I fall in love with.

Comment: Why +1 for `array_combine()`? `array_combine()` is not going to do anything here if you have the array described by OP. `array_combine()` combines an array of keys with an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate on second array and setting each element in first array

Answer (score 0):

I think `array_merge()` or `array_combine()` are the functions you are looking for
`array_merge()` may used to merge the two array which are further called.
and the `array_combine()` the keys of a array with the values of a another array.

Answer (score 0):

if you know exactly which key you want override you can simply do that like this
$first['name']="jastin";
otherwise you have to use array_merge

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a built-in function for this (simple) need, so I developed a custom function in order to override a $default array with an $override array:

```
function array_override( $default, $override )
{
    foreach( $default as $k=>$v )
    {
        if( isset( $override[$k] ) ) $default[$k] = $override[$k];
    }
    return $default;
}
```

As you can see, values in $default are overridden only if are set on the $override array; otherwise the $default value remain on the returned array.